# Elastic search csv river module not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to index csv file in elasticsearch

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/my_csv_river/_meta -d '
{
    "type" : "csv",
    "csv_file" : {
        "folder" : "/tmp",
        "filename_pattern" : ".*\\.csv$",
        "first_line_is_header" : "true",
        "field_separator" : ",",


        "field_id" : "_id"

    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "my_csv_data_1",
        "type" : "csv_type_1",
        "bulk_size" : 100,
        "bulk_threshold" : 10
    }
}'
```

after indexing while searching http://localhost:9200/my_csv_data_1/_search
got

```
{
error: "IndexMissingException[[my_csv_data_1] missing]",
status: 404
}
```

any thoughts or i missed any thing?

Comment: Rivers are no longer a supported component. You are probably better of with logstash: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html